# How to use mvexpand on an json array of key/value pairs

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql, ms-app-analytics

I have a custom property in my appInsights telemetry that is a json array of a key/value pairs.  What I want to do is project out that key/value pair and it seems that using [parsejson](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#parsejson) and [mvexpand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#mvexpand-operator) together is how to achieve this; however, I seem to be missing something.  The end result of my expression is a column named type that is the raw json.  Attempting to add any property to the expression results in an empty column.

**Json encoded property**

```
[{"type":"text/xml","count":1}]
```

**AIQL**

```
requests 
 | project customDimensions 
 | extend type=parsejson(customDimensions.['Media Types'])
 | mvexpand bagexpansion=array type
```

**Update 6/30/17**

To answer EranG's question the output of my request when projecting out the properties as columns is as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same issue recently. Probably your property already of type `dynamic`, but its dynamic `String` not the array. `parsejson` don't work because it converts `String` to `dynamic`, not dynamic to another dynamic. To work around this I suggest you to try first convert your property to `String` and then parse it again.

Please, try following example. It may help you as it helped me:

```
requests 
| project customDimensions 
| extend type=parsejson(tostring(customDimensions.['Media Types']))
| mvexpand type
| project type.type, type.['count']
```

Comment: Thanks, the tostring() is what I was missing

Answer (score 1):

What `mvexpand` does is to take your array and break it down to lines, so each line will have a single item from the array.
If you want to break each item to columns, you'll need to try something like:

```
requests 
| project customDimensions 
| extend type=parsejson(customDimensions.['Media Types'])
| mvexpand bagexpansion=array type 
| project type = type.type, count_ = type["count"]
```

Comment: unfortunately when I run that query I end up with the same number of result rows with two empty columns named type and count_